# Salt analysis (cation)

Tags: experimental-chemistry, salt

I'm reading about salt analysis and I've got some questions:

[image]
[image]
Image source: [pdf](https://ncert.nic.in/pdf/publication/sciencelaboratorymanuals/classXII/chemistry/lelm107.pdf)

Why are some sulphides (group II) precipitated in presence of HCl while others (group IV) in presence of ammonia solution? Can NaOH be used in place of ammonia solution? What's the role of NH4Cl in testing for group III? Will Na2CO3 work for group V?

(The groups here are not related to groups of periodic table.)

Comment: Too many questions in one post.

Comment: Am I the only one who noticed "not to be republished" on a "republished" photo here?

Comment: @ Mithoron. Yes. You are right. I had not seen this advice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer your three questions.

1. Some sulphides are soluble in acidic solutions (group IV). Some are insoluble in the same sort of acidic solution (group II). It is a question of solubility product. It can be taken as an experimental result, a fact.
2. If no $\ce{NH4Cl}$ were present in the solution tested for Group III, the precipitates $\ce{Al(OH)3}$ and $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$ may remain in a colloidal state, and will cross the filter paper. This is a serious drawback. In the presence of enough ions, like $\ce{NH4^+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$, the colloid is transformed into a precipitate.
3. $\ce{NaOH}$ can replace ammonia solution, but it will prevent the precipitation of $\ce{Al(OH)3}$ in group III and $\ce{Zn(OH)2}$ in group IV. These precipitates will redissolve in $\ce{NaOH}$ to form a solution of aluminate $\ce{Al(OH)4^-}$ and zincate $\ce{[Zn(OH)4]^{2-}}$. So the method would not detect $\ce{Al}$ or $\ce{Zn}$.

Comment: NH4Cl + NH3 forms a buffered solution to give the proper pH and [S=].  Using NaOH will make adjustment difficult.

Comment: Will any other soluble carbonate like Na2CO3 work for group V? @maurice

Comment: @ Shub Yes. You may replace $\ce{Na2CO3}$ by any soluble carbonate. But the choice is limited. The only soluble carbonates are ammonium, sodium, potassium, rubidium and caesium carbonates.

Comment: @Maurice you wrote *NaOH will prevent the precipitation of Al(OH)3 in group III and Zn(OH)2 in group IV.* But in group IV isn't it the sulphide that gets precipitated?

Comment: @Shub. You are right. The elements belonging to Group IV are precipitated by $\ce{H2S}$ in the systematic analysis of cations. But the same elements may also have other reactions which have nothing to do with the cation analysis. For example, they may react with $\ce{NaOH}$, and with plenty of other reagents. Here I was interested in reactions of cations with $\ce{NaOH}$. This is all, and it has no relation with the reactions of $\ce{H2S}$ or $\ce{(NH4)2S}$ in the systematic analysis of cations.